# sql server max record value grouped by id tuple from separate table

Tags: sql-server, max

There are many questions already on SO asking how to do a general max value with group by some id. However my particular case is somewhat different.

What I have is a record with a value that links to any unknown number of profiles associated (as a "team") with that record. For simplicity in the example each team has 2 profiles but the real example could have any size.

From these records I'm trying to create a leaderboard to show the max record from each unique team formation and should only show one result even if the team scored the same max value more than once.

- In this example the unique teams are (1, 2) and (2, 3).

EDIT: Unique team formation means that the leaderboard should consider all records with profiles (1, 2) to be the same unique formation of a team (as a unique id if that helps) even though the same team may have been formed multiple times for different records.

- In this example team (1,2) has a duplicate max record value of 1 which should ignore the duplicate.

Lets say was have 3 users:

```
Table: profile
profileId | name
1         | John
2         | James
3         | Mark
```

Then lets say there are currently the following records:

```
Table: record
recordId | value
1        | 1
2        | 1
3        | 2
4        | 3
```

And finally each record is made of the following teams described by their members:

```
Table: member
recordId | profileId
1        | 1
1        | 2         
2        | 1
2        | 2
3        | 2
3        | 3
4        | 3
4        | 2
```

The final output should look like:

```
recordId | profileId1 | profileId2 | value
4        | 2          | 3          | 4
1 (or 2) | 1          | 2          | 0
```

So far I've seem something like this to do it if the group id was part of the record:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM (SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY profileId ORDER BY value DESC) N
    FROM record
) M WHERE N = 1
```

And this to actually get the unique tuples:

```
select max(r.value) as value, p1.profileId as p1, p2.profileId as p2 
from record r 
inner join profile p1 on p1.recordId = r.id 
inner join profile p1 on p2.recordId = r.id  
where p1.profileId < p2.profileId
group by p2.profileId, p2.profileId
```

However, I don't know how to piece it together to get the max record for each tuple of profiles.

Also, the second query isn't very scalable for any unknown number of profiles and if there is a way to do it without self joining based on the number of profiles that would be a bonus!

If someone can help me build the right query for SQL Server that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: How is (1,2) and (2,3) unique? Also could you label with proper table name each of your data sets so that it is easy to understand? Your explanation is not in sync with the data that you have posted.

Comment: I've updated the names and the queries to be synced. The team made of (profile 1, and profile 2) is a unique formation as is the team made of (profile 2, and profile 3) even though the team may be formed of the same users multiple times. For example, me and you attempt the same activity 3 times there would be 3 sets of me and you but from the leaderboard's perspective it should only consider us as 1 team to be represented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch more research and trial and error I came to the following answer that solves my problem. This query will give the top scores from each team for a 2 person team leaderboard:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m1.profileId, m2.profileId, m3.profileId ORDER BY r.value DESC) N,
            m1.profileId AS m1, m2.profileId AS m2, m3.profileId AS m3, r.value, r.id 
        FROM record r
        INNER JOIN member m1 ON m1.recordId = r.id 
        INNER JOIN member m2 ON m2.recordId = r.id 
        WHERE m1.profileId < m2.profileId
    ) R
where N = 1
ORDER BY value DESC;
```

It works by running a partition to rank all the records by team and then plucks only the record ranked 1. The where m1.profileId < m2.profileId ensures that only 1 permutation of the team is used in the results.